# Brand/Remove Office 365 Login Page for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, branding

We have a challenge which we would like to find a solution to.

•   We are using Project Online with SharePoint Online with Office 365.

•   We are trying to find a solution to brand/ (if branding is not possible) get rid of the Office 365 log in page.

•   What we are trying to achieve is:

•   1. Users click on a link, say: https://abc.sharepoint.com/project1/
•   2. Instead of seeing Office 365 login page, we would like them to be able to see the login page with our own brand or a login box to enter username and password.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create what is called a Smart Link.  This will have the home realm discovery embedded in the request url so that the user will be directed to your local ADFS (or other federated login page).   You will not be able to have users click on https://abc.sharepoint.com/* links because there is no way to communicate to the *.sharepoint.com server what the users home realm is.  This is why it always sends the user to the Office365 login page.

If you are only concerned about this one url, then you have create something like http://project1.abc.com/ (or some other kind of short url) and then have it redirect to the Smart Link and after authentication the user will end up at https://abc.sharepoint.com/project1/

Office 365 community document on 
[using smart links or IdP initiated authentication with Office 365](http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/sso/using-smart-links-or-idp-initiated-authentication-with-office-365.aspx)