# Set a start page to your office 365 tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, personalization

Is there a way to set start page of office 365 tenant to some SharePoint site, instead of portal.office.com, after a successful login? I want to be redirected to the custom site collection once authenticated successfully.

```
https://portal.office.com/Home
```

[image]

Comment: If you go to the URL you want to end up at, and is not logged in, you will be redirected back to that URL after a successfull authentication. Is that not enough? Or what is your scenario?

Comment: Yes, just use your SharePoint portal url instead of  https://portal.office.com/Home

Comment: @RobertLindgren it's not enough. We want to set one site collection URL for all the users who log into Office 365. There are over 500 users and we want to drive this process.

Comment: @martusha how do I set this URL for all 500 users so it is consistent across all of them?

Comment: @user9216 what do you mean? It's a matter of a GPO setting the home page of the browser for example

Comment: You mean forcing this via GPO?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86089/brand-remove-office-365-login-page-for-sharepoint-online?rq=1 is an interesting alternative

Comment: If you want to see this custom URL option added for the Office 365 Start Page, you can Vote for the feature [here](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/11306136-set-custom-start-page) on the Microsoft UserVoice forum that dev teams monitor for high-demand feature requests.

Answer (score 8):

First, you can change the O365 landing page, but you can't specify a URL for the new landing page, it's a dropdown menu. See https://blogs.office.com/2014/09/18/new-office-365-home-page-fast-access-services/ for details.

Second, this setting is a per-user one. An admin cannot change this setting for all or specific users at this time.

As it's said in comments, the solution is to force each user's browser to start on a specific page of your O365 environnement, through GPO. If SSO is not enabled, then they will have to login, and after that O365 will redirect them to the right page (SharePoint site in your case)

But if users explicitly go to portal.office.com, there are no solutions at this time to redirect all of them to a specific page.

Comment: An alternative method beside GPO's is to use ADFS.  If you configure SSO with ADFS you can control which site a user is sent back to after authentication.